# ERR! code E401 npm ERR! Incorrect or missing password

Tags: node.js, npm

I am trying to do an "npm install" on my project which I have checked out and I have recieved this error :

```
npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.11: core-js@<3.3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Because of the V8 engine whims, feature detection in old core-js versions could cause a slowdown up to 100x even if nothing is polyfilled. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js.
npm ERR! code E401
npm ERR! Incorrect or missing password.
npm ERR! If you were trying to login, change your password, create an
npm ERR! authentication token or enable two-factor authentication then
npm ERR! that means you likely typed your password in incorrectly.
```

I have done a number of things.

- removed all .npmrc files on my file system.
- logged in as my npm user
- deleted package-lock.json

..but i still get the same error.

At the end of the day what I would really like to know is, WHY am I getting this error? Why when I install all my modules does it suddenly want me to log in? Is this from a particular module? What is the reasoning behind this error?

If I "npm install" a random react project I have no problems, so I guess there is something wrong in my package.json. But WHAT module is it?

I am at a complete loss.

My package.json looks like this :

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.28",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.13.0",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.1.9",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.11.4",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.11.2",
    "@stripe/react-stripe-js": "^1.1.2",
    "@stripe/stripe-js": "^1.5.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.3.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.1.2",
    "@types/node": "^16.0.1",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.14",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.9",
    "apisauce": "^1.0.1",
    "formik": "^2.1.4",
    "history": "^4.10.1",
    "jwt-decode": "^2.2.0",
    "moment": "^2.27.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.0",
    "react-router": "^5.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.1",
    "react-toastify": "^7.0.4",
    "redux": "4.0.1",
    "redux-persist": "^6.0.0",
    "redux-saga": "^1.1.3",
    "typescript": "^4.3.5"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "test-c": "jest --coverage",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jest": "^25.2.3",
    "@types/jwt-decode": "^3.1.0",
    "@types/react-redux": "^7.1.17",
    "@types/react-router": "^5.1.16",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.1.8",
    "enzyme": "^3.11.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.15.2",
    "flow-bin": "^0.152.0",
    "jest-serializer-html": "^7.0.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "^16.13.1",
    "redux-mock-store": "^1.5.4"
  }
}
```

Comment: can you share your package json

Comment: its a bit too big to paste here

Comment: can you remove package-lock.json file and after again install

Comment: tried that......

Comment: without package.json how can resolve your problem ?

Comment: ok i pasted it in ....................

Comment: from the first look it feels some of the package internally is using core-js version < 3.3, therefore, i would suggest to either upgrade your dependencies OR look for those npm packages that might need upgrade and still are using older versions of core-js